# Finding conditions for vectors in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to anwser this.

> Given the linear transformation $T(x,y)=(5x+4y,-3x-2y)$, Could it be possible to find a non-zero vector $v$ such that $T(v)=nv?$ for some $n\neq1,2$

My thinking: No, such vector $v$ does not exist. Because,

Let $v=(x,y)$,  then $T(v)=T(x,y)=(5x+4y,-3x-2y)$. Now let's assume $T(v)=nv$
in search for a vector satisfying the equation. $T(v)=nv$
$\Rightarrow$ $(5x+4y,-3x-2y)=(nx,ny)$ which gives the system of equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
5x+4y=nx \\ 
-3x-2y=ny \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Then by leaving alone $y$ from the first equation and making a substitution the second one it results in (Note the $x$ "gets eliminated") this equation $n^2-3n+2=0$. Which it's only satisfied for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Is this a strong argument to prove that it doesn't exist such $n\neq1,2$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Your transformation is represented by the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5&4\\-3&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the eigenvalues of this matrix are $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$.

This is another version of your argument ( that is correct). Can you see why?